# Splitting string using whitespace while keeping \n as a separate element

Tags: ruby, parsing, split, newline, whitespace

I am using Ruby and looking for a way to read in a sample string with the following text:

```
"This is a test
file, dog cat bark
meow woof woof"
```

and split elements into an array of characters based on whitespace, but to keep the `\n` value in the array as a separate element.

I know I can use the `string.split(/\n/)` to get

```
["this is a test", "file, dog cat bark", "meow woof woof"]
```

Also `string.split(/ /)` yields

```
["this", "is", "a", "test\nfile,", "dog", "cat", "bark\nmeow", "woof", "woof"]
```

But I am looking for a way to get:

```
["this", "is", "a", "test", "\n", "file,", "dog", "cat", "bark", "\n", "meow", "woof", "woof"]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using Ruby?

Answer (score 5):

It's a strange thing to do but:

```
string.split /(?=\n)|(?<=\n)| /
#=> ["This", "is", "a", "test", "\n", "file,", "dog", "cat", "bark", "\n", "meow", "woof", "woof"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could turn your logic around a bit and look for what you want instead of looking for the delimiters between what you want. A simple [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) like this should do the trick:

```
>> s.scan(/\S+|\n+/)
=> ["This", "is", "a", "test", "\n", "file,", "dog", "cat", "bark", "\n", "meow", "woof", "woof"]
```

That assumes that repeated `\n` should be a single token of course.

Comment: +1 I like this, and prefer looking for what is wanted. That sounds like my mantra at work when people use `gsub` to remove what they don't want, instead of matching for what they want.

Comment: Not bad, but this won't split at consecutive delimiters the way it probably should.

Comment: @pguardiario: Not sure what you mean, do you have an example? Something like `"a\n \nb"` perhaps?

Comment: How about `"a\n\nb"`. There should be 2 `\n` tokens, not 1 `\n\n` token (in my opinion).

Comment: @pguardiario: "That assumes that repeated `\n` should be a single token of course." Switching to `/\S+/\n/` takes care of your case and `/\S+|(?:\n\s*)/` would take care of my `"a\n \nb"` case.

Comment: I think your last one might be the ticket. Not much nicer than mine though.

Comment: @pguardiario: We'll have to arm wrestle for it next time we meet :) Pastry scraper versus strawberry/kiwi pie, should be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't particularly elegant, but you could try replacing `"\n"` with `" \n "` (note the spaces surrounding `\n`), and then split the resulting string on `/ /`.

Comment: Good point! eager to know the difference between `"\n"` with `" \n "`. Can you explain?

Comment: @RubyLovely the spaces on either side of `\n` become 'consumed' by `string.split(/\s/)` operation; Such that `\n` are placed in the resulting array along with any contiguous character strings that aren't spaces.  Also, I need to correct my answer to `/ /` and not `/\s/`, since `/\s/` also includes `\n` and a number of other whitespace characters.

Comment: `+1` for explanation. How is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965938/ensure-that-multiple-variables-have-a-different-value)?

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd request, and perhaps, if you told us *WHY* you want to do that, we could help you do it in a more straightforward and conventional fashion.

It looks like you're trying to split the words and still know where your original line-ends were. Having the lines split into individual words is useful for many things, but keeping the line-ends... not so much in my experience.

When I'm dealing with text and need to break the lines up for processing, I do it this way:

```
text = "This is a test
file, dog cat bark
meow woof woof"

data = text.lines.map(&:split)
```

At this point, `data` looks like:

```
[["This", "is", "a", "test"],
 ["file,", "dog", "cat", "bark"],
 ["meow", "woof", "woof"]]
```

I know that each sub-array was a separate line, so if I need to process by lines I can do it using an iterator like `each` or `map`, or to reconstruct the original text I can `join(" ")` the sub-array elements, then `join("\n")` the resulting lines:

```
data.map{ |a| a.join(' ') }.join("\n")
=> "This is a test\nfile, dog cat bark\nmeow woof woof"
```