# Ensure that multiple variables have a different value

Tags: ruby

I have to compare multiple variables and check if they are different. Is there any smooth way to do this? I can do

```
var1 = 3
var2 = "test"
var3 = 100

if var1 != var2 && var1 != var3 && var2 != var3
  ...
end
```

But if the list of variables are getting longer, this becomes unhandy. I thought about something like `var1 != var2 != var3` but that doesn't work. So maybe there is a simple Ruby-way to do this.

Comment: with your philosophy `var1 != var2 != var3` do you want to continue if `var1 != var2` is `true` for `var3` also? or vice-versa?

Comment: Equality is transitive but inequality is not transitive.

Comment: @sawa is right, even if a chained notation existed, `var1 != var2 != var3` would be a shorthand for `var1 != var2 && var2 != var3`, it wouldn't ensure that `var1 != var3`, thus "failing" for `3 != 5 != 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uniq`'s destructive counterpart [`uniq!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) to determine if an array contains duplicates. It returns `nil` if no duplicates were found:

```
if ![var1, var2, var3].uniq!
  # no duplicates
end
```

Comment: Great, I knew that there is always a cool way to do such things in Ruby. thx!

Answer (score 3):

One way might be using Array#uniq.

```
inputs = [var1, var2, var3]

if inputs.uniq == inputs
  # ...
end

# or

if inputs.uniq.length == inputs.length
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
a = [var1. var2, var3]

if a.length == a.uniq.length
 ..
end
```

Comment: thx for the reply! Your solution is like the one from Stefan (his is a little bit shorter), so I would love to give you also a questions solved

Answer (score 0):

You can using a mapping to store them,and compare its length with your input variable.